Why cant i add into toD a jpa with insert req
i have a route camel 4.0.0 with toD(query_jpa)
but when running a field have XML string, with pre:timestamp2024-07-13T11:06:25+02:00</pre:timestamp>, the '+' desaspear on database.... and replacing by SPACE caracter.  OK i know than toD use the URI HTTP , but i want keep all xml to insert on column database.
i have try into query a RAW(${header.xmlresponse})

INSERT INTO xxxx SET x,y,z values (x,y,RAW(${header.xmlResponse})

but the same thing... a lose the '+' caracter in db...
how can insert xml without lose something.
Thanks you.

Assuming you have a route like this:
...
.toD("sql:INSERT INTO xxxx SET x,y,z values (x,y,RAW(${header.xmlResponse})")
...

you can try to use an external sql file like:
resources/sql/insert.sql
INSERT INTO xxxx SET x,y,z values (x,y, :#xmlResponse)

and then use it like this in your route:
...
.toD("sql:classpath:sql/insert.sql")
...

By using an external file instead of the uri notation, every character should be preserved.

i try, but i have message : no endpoint cound found for sql://classpath:database/query_insertDoc.sql , please check your classpath....
im on quarkus platform 3.4.3  with camel 4.0.0
But i have in my projet folder : src/main/resources/database/query_insertDoc.sql
MMHHH quarkus change no read resources directory and dont add into classpath ?
strange..
